# How to find usable screen size in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I know we get the screen size using screen.height and screen.width. 
I am interested in knowing how to find the usable screen area using Javascript.
This is like screen height minus address bar height minus toolbar etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For most browser you can read `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`, for Internet Explorer its `document.documentElement.clientWidth` and  `document.documentElement.clientHeight`, I think...

Comment: ah, I'm just paranoid because of traumatic experiences with IE6 :-D

Comment: @ZeroPage: It's ok, IE6 is dead, and is never coming back.

Answer (score 3):

Use `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth`